# What is the formula in excel to put single quotations around a number and NOT change the number?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, char

I am trying to convert a simple number 0001 to single quotes around it '0001'. The issue I am having is that its creating the single quotes, but its converting the number to 1.  If I convert the column to text it changes it from 0001 to 1 , which I dont want. I am trying to use the CHAR(39) function.. =CHAR(39)&B1&CHAR(39)

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with `="'"&B1&"'"`?

Comment: This also drops the leading zeros

Comment: Just added a second image to show you.

Comment: `="'"&text(B1,"0000")&"'"`

Comment: How do I mark it as solved? Thanks again

Comment: Click the check mark by my answer below.

Comment: The number in `B1` is actually `1` formatted as `0000` you can force that within a formula the way Scott Craner described.

Answer (score 0):

Use TEXT to format the number like it is formatted in the cell:

```
="'"&TEXT(B1,"0000")&"'"
```

Comment: Or `=TEXT(B1,"'0000'")`. Maybe OP can just apply number formatting too.